# Getting 4 decimal places in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query that I'm, trying to run:

```
SELECT questionid,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN correct = FALSE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::decimal(10,4) / COUNT(*)::decimal(10,4))::decimal(10,4) AS PercentWrong,
       COUNT(questionid) AS Questions
FROM asmt.testscores
WHERE testscoreid IN (SELECT DISTINCT test_score_id
                      FROM ads.fbs_assessment_adaptive_pause_staging)
AND   answered = TRUE
AND   memberid IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY questionid
ORDER BY PercentWrong
```

I would like to have the column `PercentWrong` to have 4 decimal places but the above query gives me only 2 decimal places despite having `decimal(10,4)`. I tried using `real` also but it gave me no decimal places at all.

How do I get 4 decimal places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [to_char](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html)

```
SELECT questionid,
       to_char(SUM(CASE WHEN correct = FALSE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::float / COUNT(*)::float,'99D9999') AS PercentWrong,
       COUNT(questionid) AS Questions
FROM asmt.testscores
WHERE testscoreid IN (SELECT DISTINCT test_score_id
                      FROM ads.fbs_assessment_adaptive_pause_staging)
AND   answered = TRUE
AND   memberid IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY questionid
ORDER BY PercentWrong
```